# Laravel 5 eloquent relationship returns empty or null but the code seems ok

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent, relation

I did some searching but still I can't solve this, I'm coding a little library site for learning and I can't get relationships to work. (libro = book, autore = author, genere = genre)

In my tinker the command

```
$libro->autore
```

returns null or empty, even if I call it as a method and use toArray

this is my code :

**Libro model**

```
namespace App;
```

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

```
class Libro extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'libri';
    protected $fillable = ['titolo', 'id_autore', 'pubblicazione', 'trama', 'voto', 'image_url', 'id_genere'];
    public function genere() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Genere');
    }

    public function autore() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Autore');
    }
}
```

**Autore Model**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Autore extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'autori';
    protected $fillable = ['nome', 'cognome', 'nascita', 'paese'];

    public function libri() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Libro');
    }
    public function getFullNameAttribute()
    {
        return $this->nome . " " . $this->cognome;
    }
}
```

**The relation in my migration**

```
$table->foreign('id_autore')->references('id')->on('autori');
$table->foreign('id_genere')->references('id')->on('generi');
```

I added the foreign keys in the mysql db, checked that on phpmyadmin, but still, it doesn't work, what am I doing wrong?

**adding more tinker responses to try outs **
If I try:

```
>>> App\Autore::find(2)->libri()->get()
```

I get:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'libri.autore_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `libri` where `libri`.`autore_id` = 2 and `libri`.`autore_id` is not null)'
```

If I try :

```
$libro-autore()
```

I get :

```
BadMethodCallException with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::autore()'
```

instead

```
$libro->autore
```

remains

```
null
```

Comment: can you add your controller logic.

Comment: I'm using tinker for showing content, I don't understand what's the point of pasting the controller which only do things for the views

Comment: have you tried $libro->autore()

Comment: Yes, I'm also adding more tinker responses to the main post, read it up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your naming convention on the columns in your relation are incorrect (backwards). The convention is `${related_table}_id`.

To solve this, alter your migration. Othwise, if you don't want to just adjust your migration, then specify the foreign key column in your `Autore` model as the 2nd argument to your `hasMany` relationship.

```
public function libri() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Libro', 'id_autore')
}
```

And make sure to do the inverse for the `Libro` model.

Comment: So the foreign keys don't set it automatically? I thought the combination of ->foreign and ->references would've set that

Comment: The database schema and the model pattern have no knowledge of each other. You must explicitly tell them how to communicate.

Comment: Also I'm sorry but tinker still returns empty arrays, and $libro->autore still gets null

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I had to add that also to the belongsTo, thanks a lot! that was my problem, sorry for bein blind not seeing that wrong sql query

Comment: @K3nzie Sorry, had to step away. I should've clarified you need to do the inverse as well. My apologies.